# How to clear a date from input type="date" with WebdriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm now using `WebdriverIO` and developing a web app.
these days I tried to set a date from input `type="date"`, I got errors

> invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear
>   it.

and found that
I could get rid of the errors by using `addValue()` but still the value won't be cleared by any API.

```
client.clearElement('#deadline')
```

Also get

> invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear
>   it.

**How can I remove the value from the form?**

Answer (score 1):

You can run in browser script to clear it

```
browser.execute(function () {
 document.querySelector('#deadline').value = '';
}, null);
```

OR give it some value

```
var date = '2020-03-28';
browser.execute(function (date) {
 document.querySelector('#deadline').value = date';
}, date);
```

reference: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/386

A more elegant way is to create a custom command and put this piece of code inside

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me:

```
client.selectorExecute("#dateInput", function(inputs, value) {
    // you can run over the inputs
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'date') // any condition
            inputs[i].value = "1973-12-09";
    }

    // or just do that:
    inputs[i].value = "1973-12-09";
    return;
})
```